# Fit action without parameters into Action<T>

Tags: c#, generics

I have this method

```
private void ProcessItem<T>(FileSystemInfo itemInfo, int itemMinAge, Action<T> action, T parameter, string errorMessage, string successMessage = "")
```

which fits for 7 of my 8 calls, e.g.

```
ProcessItem<bool>(subDir, dir.MinAge, subDir.Delete, true, string.Format(Messages.NotDeletedFolder, subDir.FullName));
```

which takes a directory and then if `dir.MinAge` meets some criteria, is calls `subDir.Delete(true)` on the directory and logs a message. But I also have one call where parameter `action` needs to be without `<T>` parameter, because I need pass a `void` method without any parameters.

Is there a way how to fit this one call into this method? I don't want to create another method just because of one call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ProcessItem<object>(subDir, dir.MinAge,
    ignored => subDir.NoArgs(),
    /* ignored */ null,
    string.Format(Messages.NotDeletedFolder, subDir.FullName));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ProcessItem<bool>(subDir, dir.MinAge, _ => ParameterlessCall() , true, ...
```

Using `_` as the parameter name in a lambda expression is a functional programming idiom for a parameter whose value never needs to be inspected.

Comment: I don't like underscores in code. You have a point, but not everyone knows functional programming. I'll use a word expression.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably just to use a lambda expression.

```
ProcessItem<bool>( ... (param) => myMethod(), ... );
```

In this case the parameter `param` will simply be ignored and `myMethod` will be invoked as normal.

Answer (score 1):

Create an optional parameter and adjust the implementation accordingly:

```
private void ProcessItem<T>(FileSystemInfo itemInfo, int itemMinAge, Action<T> action = null, Action action2 = null, T parameter, string errorMessage, string successMessage = "")
```

Comment: Acceptable, but a little bit clumsy in my opinion. Anyway, thank you.